# CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "[ { '$add': [ 250, 32 ] } ]" at path "balance" at model.Query.exec + path

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update(add) the balance stored in the mongodb database whenever user makes a transaction. Here is the code. The value gets updated but cannot perform the add operation instead shows the CastError.

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:user._id}, {balance: [{$add: [user.balance,createdTransaction.amount]}]}, {new:true},((err,data)=>{
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: You can try `{ balance: { $inc: createdTransaction.amount } }`

Comment: @turivishal Getting similar error with $ inc..
CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "{ '$inc': 42 }" at path "balance" at model.Query.exec...  Here 42 is the createdTransaction.amount that I am passing.